# Inject DataProtection based on injected user options IOptions<> in ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I'm a little bit confused here regarding how to inject DataProtection in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` based on user settings being as well injected from `services.Configure<UserSettingsConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings"));`.

The values `appName_from_appsettings_json` and `dirInfo_from_appsettings_json` below should be coming from the injected UserSettingsConfig and would be accessible anywhere else by injecting `IOptions<UserSettingsConfig>` but not here.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.Configure<UserSettingsConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings"));
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddScoped<DevOnlyActionFilter>();

    services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName(appName_from_appsettings_json)
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(dirInfo_from_appsettings_json);
}
```

I've found ways to achieve my goals without using DI with code like `var sharedDataProtectionAppName = configuration.GetValue<string>("UserSettings:SharedDataProtection:ApplicationName");`

I had the feeling I have found the solution in this article http://andrewlock.net/access-services-inside-options-and-startup-using-configureoptions/ by it seems like I can't figure out how to apply it to my case. I would need a way to inject `DataProtection` based on values from the injected `IOptions<UserSettingsConfig>`. What would be the cleanest way to do that in your opinion?

UPDATE: I found a solution based on that type of code that I could be calling from `ConfigureServices`, but I still wonder if it's the best way.

```
var userSettingsConfig = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetServices<IOptions<UserSettingsConfig>>().First();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the extension method `.Bind()`. This method will try to bind the value to the Configuration object by matching the keys from the configuration.

```
// Add framework services.
var userSettingsConfig = new UserSettingsConfig();
Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings").Bind(userSettingsConfig);
services.Configure<UserSettingsConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings"));

services.AddMvc();
services.AddScoped<DevOnlyActionFilter>();

services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName(userSettingsConfig.appName)
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(userSettingsConfig.DirInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is better than extracting the UserSettings config from the service provider as I'm doing right now (`var userSettingsConfig = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetServices<IOptions<UserSettingsConfig>>().First();`).

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow.